# Haml not parsing the element with a dash in it's name

Tags: python, angularjs, haml

Given this haml code

```
%uib-pagination{:boundary-links => "true", :total-items => "totalItems", :ng-model => "currentPage", :class => "pagination-sm", :previous-text => "&lsaquo;", :next-text => "&rsaquo;", :first-text => "&laquo;", :last-text => "&raquo;"}
```

the output looks like this

```
<uib>-pagination{:boundary-links =&gt; "true", :total-items =&gt; "totalItems", :ng-model =&gt; "currentPage", :class =&gt; "pagination-sm", :previous-text =&gt; "‹", :next-text =&gt; "›", :first-text =&gt; "«", :last-text =&gt; "»"}</uib>
```

Is it possible to set the dashy name?

Comment: How are you generating the HTML? The Ruby implementation of Haml won’t give that result, you’ll get an error like ``undefined local variable or method `links'`` (you’ll need to use strings in the attributes rather than symbols to avoid that).

Comment: @matt, I'm using the `hamlpy` python library.

Answer (score 0):

In HamlPy, regex used to extract tag name is `?P<tag>%\w+(\:\w+)?`, so it's not possible to set dashy name.

Just replace it with underscore:

```
[thyrst@THy tmp]$ cat file.haml
%uib_pagination{:boundary-links => "true", :total-items => "totalItems", :ng-model => "currentPage", :class => "pagination-sm", :previous-text => "&lsaquo;", :next-text => "&rsaquo;", :first-text => "&laquo;", :last-text => "&raquo;"}

[thyrst@THy tmp]$ hamlpy file.haml
<uib_pagination class='pagination-sm' boundary-links='true' total-items='totalItems' ng-model='currentPage' previous-text='&lsaquo;' next-text='&rsaquo;' first-text='&laquo;' last-text='&raquo;'></uib_pagination>
```